# Bluetooth not working on lenovo u400 after upgrading to windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop

Upgraded from windows 7. I have everything else working except for bluetooth even after trying many guides to fix it. From the task manager I can see that bluetooth support services are running. However the bluetooth option is no longer available in pc settings. I have looked for drivers but apparently it should be free-driving. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Re-download & install the Bluetooth driver. [This](http://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-u-series-laptops/ideapad-u400) should resolve the issue.

Comment: I have checked here, but none of these drivers say they are for bluetooth. Is it included in one of the other drivers?

Answer (score -1):

Well there are many possible ways to troubleshoot this problem. Only to look for the drivers isn't enoght for that.

Have you tried to follow [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/why-isnt-windows-finding-device) bluetooth troubleshooting instruction from Microsoft?

But also with [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=bluetooth%20troubleshooting%20windows%208.1) you can find many troubleshoot guides like [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/bluetooth-devices-not-showing-windows) for bluetooth problems in Windows 8.1.

Bevore you post an question, research how to solve it by your own. First thing that I do when I have a Problem I search in Microsoft help guide for possible solutions.

Comment: I have indeed followed this guide and tried many others. Of course I googled it first. Most guides involved turning on the setting (which no longer exists) or making sure the services are running (which they are). Not sure why you assumed I didn't do anything before asking.